# Setting a button enabled

Tags: android

I have a main page that has a 2 buttons, button1 is enabled and button2 is disabled. button1 will open  2nd page that has 1 button named button3. button3 will intent BACK to the main page and it should make the button2 enabled. the problem is button2 will become enabled for a short period then back to being disabled(shaded).

Main page.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Enable extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable);


    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), p2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button page2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), p2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_enable, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

2nd page

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class p2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.p2);

    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Enable.class);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable);
            Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            a.setEnabled(true);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });

}
}
```

XML of main page

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Enable" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Button" />
```

XML of page2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of controlling the behaviour of button via the XML, control the enable and disable feature in the activity code. Hope this will help

Comment: Completely disagree - XML is great for initialisation of values such as enabled, and in code is the only way that you can alter them post-layout, so I'm not exactly sure what you're on about!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with how Intents work. What your second activity is doing is accessing the layout of the first activity (which is bad practice as they're now tightly coupled), but the intent is recreating the Main activity - which means the onCreate method gets called again, and the button is recreated - with the enabled property set to false.

To fix your issue, either take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) article, which covers Intents, intent extras (to pass data - which will allow you to set a property which your Main activity can use to determine whether to enable the button), and intent flags (to manipulate how instances of your classes operate - one option is to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` which takes any existing instance and puts it at the top of the stack), or just search for information on flags and extras, they should show you what you need to know.

Comment: anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: I practically gave you one. I'm not going to do your code for you - you'll learn much more my researching it all yourself, and trust me, it's a lot more satisfying

Answer (score 0):

The Intent starts the activity again, and the activity calls the onCreate method, which sets the Button 2 to disabled.

Comment: what should I do to prevent it from being disabled?

Comment: Try calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable); after enabling the button.